# Writing Multiline text in a string

Tags: python

Assume we want to have a string of this form:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

I don't have access to all lines at one time and I get them one by one in different parts of my code. So, I want to have a string and update the string when I have a new line to write there.

I can write each line in a string, but when I use "\n" to go the next line like this

```
str = "a b c" + "\n" + "d e f" + "\n" + "g h i" 
str
```

this is the output:

```
'a b c\nd e f\ng h i'
```

Any idea for making the output correct?

Comment: Can you edit your question to share the code that doesn't work?

Comment: define "it doesn't work"

Comment: Show us the not-working code and tell us what you were hoping it would do.

Comment: I copied your source code into python 2.7.  It produced the correct output.  I copied your `str` into python 3.5, and ran `print(str)`.  It also produced the correct output.  There must be something you're not showing us.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein You are right. I made a mistake. I didn't write print str. I just typed str in python console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type a variable name in the python shell, it returns the value of that variable.  In your case, the value of `str` does have embedded `\n` in it.  (As you know from the way you're using it, a string can have any number of newlines in it.)  The shell is displaying the raw value of the string.

If you do anything with that string, however, you'll see the newlines behaving as you expect them to.

For example, `print(str)` outputs the string formatted in the way you expect it to be.

Similarly,

```
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write(str)
```

will produce a file called `myfile.txt` with the three lines that you want to see in it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to print it, this seems to work for me.

```
print("a b c \nd e f \ng h i")
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is three quotes.

```
string="""a b c
d e f
g h i"""

print(string)
```